# How to use UIPopoverController to edit a UIlabel

Tags: uilabel, selector, uipopovercontroller

Ive created a UIPopover Controller in my view controller which opens a popup that contains a list of items in it. Im wanting it so that if I choose an item in the list a label on the main view is updated to show this selection. Ive tried using the code below so far but when I click on an item on the list I get the following error: -[ASHAppDelegate portfolioLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e4fe80

The code Ive used for the UIPopOverController is shown below:

-(IBAction) portFoliosButtonPress:(id)sender {

```
if (self.portfolioPopoverController == nil) {
    ASHPortfolioViewController *portfoliosTableViewController = [[ASHPortfolioViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    //CGSize frame = {portfoliosTableViewController.view.frame.size.width, 200.0};
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:portfoliosTableViewController]; 
     CGSize frame = {300.0, 230.0};
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:frame];
    popover.delegate = self;

    self.portfolioPopoverController = popover;
    //self.contentSizeForViewInPopover.height = CGSizeMake(150.0, 140.0);
}

if ([self.portfolioPopoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [self.portfolioPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];    
}
else {
    [self.portfolioPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
self.portfolioLabel.text = @"hi";

}
#pragma mark - Popover lifecycle

//---called when the user clicks outside the popover view---
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {

NSLog(@"popover about to be dismissed");
return YES;
}

//---called when the popover view is dismissed---
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:
(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {

    NSLog(@"popover dismissed");    
}
```

The code used in my UITableView that the popover controller contains is shown below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{

    ASHFirstViewController *appDelegate =(ASHFirstViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    appDelegate.portfolioLabel.text = @"Test"; 
}
```

'portfolioLabel' is an IBOutlet UIlabel I have in my view controller.